# What is more harmful in a car crash - restrciting movement or allowing some movement to reduce g-force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, collision

Sorry if I haven't worded the title very well, feel free to improve.

Let me explain before I ask my question...

We have purchased a [car carrier](https://www.petbarn.com.au/playmate-airline-spec-open-top-pet-carrier-white-grey-medium) (small version) for our dog and also purchased [some straps](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005SH05E6) to secure it to the seat; however we have noticed that even though it is secured to the seatbelt it is still a little loose (you can move the carrier forward a bit before it attempts to prevent further movement).

I have heard someone else that has used these same straps state they have instead put the straps around the whole back of the seat rather than use the seatbelt and they have stated it is now much more secure/tighter against the seat and hence prevents much movement.

So my question is - which method is better/safer?

- Securing it around the seat, to me, *seems* like it may be a better option as it helps prevent movement, but I'm wondering, because of this lack of movement, would our dog now have to sustain more **g-force**?
- Securing it to the seatbelt, to me, would seem to propel the carrier forward on an impact until it is stopped and then our dog would be thrown forward into the front of the carrier in a more "jerky" fashion then when secure but *may* not have to sustain as much g-force!?

As a side note, if it matters, we have been told by [CPS](https://www.centerforpetsafety.org/) that the straps we purchased are **not** *strength rated*; which I assume means they have the potential to break at high points of impact, but we are open to purchasing better ones if need be, but I am also cautious about using straps not specifically made for carriers as I have heard using seatbelts around carriers [can potentially crush them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnES6NIMHsM).

Comment: What hurts more, falling on a mattress or on a glass floor?

Comment: I think that damage on a human depends on physics but also on physiology.

Comment: @my2cts How does that relate to this question since our dog would be hitting the same surface? ...or do you mean allowing the carrier to have movement and go forward would end up in hitting the side of the carrier harder (glass) or hitting the surface in a more controlled state and more or less "pressing" up against it more (mattress)? But really, it's not about what _hurts more_, it's about what causes the most damage.

Comment: Adding to the last paragraph of the answer below, Impulse (integral of force over time) equals change in momentum. The change in momentum of the occupant is the product of mass times initial speed (as the final speed is 0). The longer the time for the interaction i.e. the longer the range of the integral, the smaller is the average force over that interval. But in a car you don't want it so long that you hit something in front of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A body in motion has an inertia of motion by virtue of which it tries to maintain it's previous state of motion(both speed and direction). For example it is noticed that on suddenly applying brakes to stop we are jerked in forward direction which is due to the inertia of motion.

Now when we are in enclosed space we must take care of the fact that if we don't stop, relative to the nearby objects,  then it is quite probable that we may get hurt. So what to do then? Answer is to somehow attach ourselves to the surrounding so that when they stop our body stops with the them. But there is another problem which is of the case that on making our body to stop suddenly by applying constraints causes a lot of force on our body which can cause minor/sever damage and can be lethal.

So what should we do then?

The right thing is the case which is somewhere inbetween i.e., to make our bodies stop in such amount of time that a comparatively lesser force acts on us but we stop in such distance that our head or other part doesn't collide with the nearby object. So my suggestion is to do the thing in which both are satisfied.

---

$$\pmb {\underline {\text {Further Reading }}}$$

- [The Statistics: Car Safety and Pets in America](https://www.petprosupplyco.com/a/s/pages/car-accident-pet-statistics-america)
- [How to Keep Your Pets Safe When Traveling](http://www.petprosupplyco.com/pages/how-to-keep-your-pets-safe-when-traveling)
- [Pet Travel Safety - How To Travel Long Distance | American Red Cross](https://www.redcross.org/get-help/how-to-prepare-for-emergencies/pet-travel-safety.html)
- [Travel Safety Tips | ASPCA](https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/general-pet-care/travel-safety-tips)

Comment: Thanks makes sense. So, going by what you wrote, it seems using the straps on the seatbelt is the best option as, what you say, it is doing "both" - it is not preventing movement to the point where there is a lot of force on their body, but also helping prevent motion enough to avoid hurting themselves.

Comment: @Brett while searching for statistics I have found some articles which I am going to attach for the reference.

Comment: Thank you - I will check them out :)

Answer (score 4):

The short answer to the question as posed in the title to your post is both.

The purpose of the seatbelt is to restrain you so that you stop with the car thereby making your stopping distance the same as the car and greater than if you had no seatbelt. Without the seat belt your inertia keeps you moving forward at the same velocity until you impact an object in the car which then stops you. You are then at the mercy of how much "give" the object has since that will determine your stopping distance.

A crash which stops the car and driver must take away all its kinetic energy according to the work energy principle which states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy, or

$$F_{ave}d=-\frac{mv^2}{2}$$

Where $F_{ave}$ = the average force you experience.

$d$ = your (and the vehicles) stopping distance.

$m$ =  your mass

$v$  =  your (and vehicle) relative velocity with wall before the crash

The vehicles crumple zone, seat belts, and air bags are all designed to increase your stopping distance and/or absorb the energy of the impact.

On the other hand, seat belts with a moderate amount of stretch further increases the stopping distance of the occupant, additionally reducing the average force experienced by the occupant while still restraining the occupant from impacting the objects within the vehicle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. Without the belt objects in the car stop you and your at the mercy of how much they “give” in terms of your stopping distance. Before there were seat belts at one time dashboards were made of metal (I know as a kid my face impacted a metal dashboard!). Then we got padded dashboards. Then seat belts. Then air bags.

Comment: _The purpose of the seatbelt is to restrain you so that you stop with the car thereby making your stopping distance greater than if you had no seatbelt._ If you had _no seatbelt_ wouldn't your stopping distance generally be greater?

Comment: Hello all. I have updated my answer. Sorry I assumed you all realized that with no seat belt when the car stops you continue with the same velocity until you impact something in the car and that brings you to a stop. Then your actual stopping distance is dictated by the object in the car, rather than the cars stopping distance..

Comment: Oh I think I understand it now. As you say, _with_ the seatbelt you are stopping _with_ the car, your body isn't physically going a greater distance in the car itself, but it takes longer to _stop_; but _without_ a seatbelt your body is generally going to go a greater distance, however your body will take a short distance to come to a stop because you will likely hit an object before the car stops!?

Comment: @Brett That is exactly correct. Without the seat belt the distance the body moves before impacting an object in the car is not a stopping distance because you continue to move with the same velocity.  Stopping distance is when you are decelerating.

Answer (score 2):

When your car drives head-on into an unyielding obstacle, the front end of the car will absorb energy by "crumpling." The relatively rigid passenger compartment will take somewhat more time to come to a stop than the front bumper will take, and so the passenger compartment *and anything that is rigidly attached to the passenger compartment* will experience a lower peak acceleration than the front bumper will experience.

Instead of a car, Let's imagine a bus that runs head on into a wall while traveling at 60 miles per hour, with your dog on the back seat.  If your dog is not strapped in, then as the bus starts to crumple, your dog will continue at 60 miles per hour, flying through the air, until it impacts the front of the bus, which likely will have come to a compete stop by that time. But, if your dog is strapped in to the back seat, then it, and the back seat, will slow down more gently while the front of the bus is crumpling.

The difference might not be as great in a shorter car, but I'd still rather be strapped in than not.

---

P.S., When the police officer looked at me, sitting unhurt on the grass next to the wreck of my car he said, "I don't need to ask whether you were wearing your seat belt." I guess he'd seen enough people who were and enough who weren't to be able to tell the difference.

Comment: _sitting unhurt on the grass next to the wreck of my car_... When I first read this, I thought you were saying you'd been thrown clear and had miraculously landed uninjured. I guess you mean you _were_ belted up and survived because of that?

Comment: @OscarBravo, That is correct. I climbed out the window, which fortunately had been open at the time of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I refer you Bob D's answer above for the physics.

At the moment of impact, the carrier will move forward until it reaches the limit of the restraining straps. The straps then undergo a deformation (elastic and inelastic), over the scale of a few centimetres, that decelerates the load. This process is the same whether the straps are loose or tight because the load is moving at the same speed at the moment when they reach their limit and begin to bite.

So it doesn't really matter if the straps are very tight or not. As long as they not so slack that the carrier can move forward enough to impact something in front.

Comment: You have missed Bob D's point, it is better to slow with the seat than to do all that slowing at once farther from the seat. As he stated, correctly, straps should be tight, or tight with some elasticity.

Comment: @AdrianHoward And what makes you _slow with the seat_? You've missed my point: the straps are the only thing that slow you and they only begin to do that when they take up the slack. At that point, your speed is the same independent of the amount of slack [pedants note: always assuming the slack is not so large that you hit the dashboard].

Comment: Being strapped snugly to the seat will help you start decelerating with the seat. Modern cars are designed to crumple up on severe impact, giving you as much deceleration time as possible, even if it hits a solid cement wall. Having loose belts will lose you some of that deceleration time as you continue forward, unrestrained, until the slack is taken up.

Comment: Also in a severe enough frontal impact, the dashboard will move closer to the seat.

Comment: @AdrianHoward It's a bit counter-intuitive: It's *only* the belt that stops you - the seat has nothing to do with it. Whether you take up 1mm or 3cm of slack before the belt bites is irrelevant - you're moving at the same speed when the belt finally tightens.

Comment: Yes, but the frame holding the belt has slowed more in that extra time so the belt hits you harder. Snug against the seat is just as far back as you can get for a front impact, it is also more secure in a side impact.

Comment: @AdrianHoward That's a good point... But in every case the belt has to do the same amount of work to stop you.

Comment: Yes, but decelerating you in, say, 1 second is much better than decelerating you in 1/2 second.